# setText("") crashes Android application

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext, settext

After hours of research and testing I haven't been able to figure out why my app is crashing when I invoke this

```
    inputLocation.setText("");  inputLocation.setText(null);
```

It will work just fine with this:

```
    inputLocation.setText("your text");
```

or

```
    inputLocation.setText(editText.getText().toString());
```

etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

**inputLocation.addTextChangedListener**

```
    // / Execute code without the use of the save changes button.
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////
    inputLocation.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            /* Process to check type */
            String location_string = inputLocation.getText().toString();
            String first_location_char = location_string.substring(0, 1);
            if (inputLocation.getText().toString().length() == locationsize) {
                String last_location_char = location_string.substring(8);

                if (last_location_char.equals("L")
                        && first_location_char.equals("L")) {

                    inputLocation.setText(location_string.substring(1, 8),
                            TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    new UpdateLocation().execute();

                } else if (!first_location_char.isEmpty()
                        && !last_location_char.isEmpty()) {

                    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            CheckLocationActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Wrong Code for Location");
                    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Please scan one more time the correct barcode!");

                    alertDialog.setButton(-1, getString(R.string.Ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    inputLocation.setText("",
                                            TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                                }
                            });
                    /*
                     * alertDialog.setButton(-2, getString(R.string.No), new
                     * DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     * 
                     * @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                     * int which) { // do nothing dialog will dismiss } });
                     */
                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    // / Execute code without the use of the save changes button.
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////
```

**Code Section**

```
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            CheckLocationActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Wrong Code for Location");
                    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Please scan one more time the correct barcode!");

                    alertDialog.setButton(-1, getString(R.string.Ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    inputLocation.setText("",
                                            TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                                }
                            });
                    /*
                     * alertDialog.setButton(-2, getString(R.string.No), new
                     * DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     * 
                     * @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                     * int which) { // do nothing dialog will dismiss } });
                     */
                    alertDialog.show();
```

**Log File**

```
11-05 16:41:33.638: W/dalvikvm(19191): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41513700)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=1
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.dev.assetlocation.CheckLocationActivity$3.onTextChanged(CheckLocationActivity.java:162)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.dev.assetlocation.CheckLocationActivity$2.onTextChanged(CheckLocationActivity.java:103)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7377)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9076)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:673)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:197)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 16:41:33.648: E/AndroidRuntime(19191):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 16:41:36.201: D/libEGL(19240): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
11-05 16:41:36.201: D/libEGL(19240): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
11-05 16:41:36.201: D/libEGL(19240): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
11-05 16:41:36.211: I/Adreno200-EGL(19240): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
11-05 16:41:36.241: D/OpenGLRenderer(19240): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: that in your code : `com.dev.assetlocation.CheckLocationActivity$3.onTextChanged(CheckLocationActivity.java:162)`

Comment: The $3 in the class name means you have anonymous classes in your code. Should still line up with line 162 (or nearby) in your CheckLocationActivity class file.

Comment: Please post your onTextChanged code

Comment: I just added inputLocation.addTextChangedListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.dev.assetlocation.CheckLocationActivity$3` (anonymous inner class #3) listens for changes of that text. `onTextChanged` (in `CheckLocationActivity$3`) uses `String.substring`, which causes your error, as there are no valid indexes in an empty `String`.

Your listener (CheckLocationActivi‌​ty.java line 162) should check whether the text is empty or `null`.

Comment: Wasn't checking for the string I added this to check the TextField before doing anything else.
`if (!inputItemNum.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) { . . .`

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0;
```

Based on above message my guess is, some where in your code you are doing some string operation (like `substring()`) on that text. If String is `""` and do `subString()` you will get `StringIndexOutofBoundsException`.

If String is `null`, you will get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Calling `substring` on `null` will rarely give you a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @still_learning: correct, not rarely, it will always give NullPointerException. Let me update answer